# Body Writer not found for Form & application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have jersey-client-2.25.1 on my build path and I know it has the default provider to convert javax.ws.rs.core.Form to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

But for this code:

```
private ClientResponse getResponse(Authorization authInstance, Form formData) {
    return webResourceInstance.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).
        header("Authorization",encode(authInstance)).
            post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
}
```

I keep getting:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class javax.ws.rs.core.Form, and MIME media type, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
```

I should not have to register a MultiPart class as per [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e7885).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have jersey-client-2.25.1 on my build path

Yeah, but you're not using it. You're using the Jersey 1.x client. `ClientResposne,WebResource`, that is jersey 1.x. Jersey (JAX-RS) 1, doesn't support `javax.ws.rs.core.Form`. That is a JAX-RS 2 class. If you *do* use your Jersey 2 client, it would work.

If you want to stick with the Jersey 1.x client, then (with application/x-www-form-urlencoded), it supports `com.sun.jersey.api.representation.Form` and `MultivaluedMap`